# Error : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed Please help I am new at android

Tags: android, eclipse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HelloActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
</textview>
```

Comment: For starters, `</textview>` is missing a capital `T` and doesn't make sense if the line before it doesn't end with a `>`. Alternatively, use `<TextView ... />`, so you don't need a separate closing tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355454/how-to-fix-error-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be)

Answer (score 1):

Not a concrete question, but [Is there a difference between 'valid xml' and 'well formed xml'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134494/is-there-a-difference-between-valid-xml-and-well-formed-xml) and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to end first TextView tag.
The  must be between the  tags like this:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".HelloActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the below code : -

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

with : -

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

If this works then please mark this answer as accepted.